# How to use docker in scripted jenkins pipeline on RHEL7

Tags: docker, jenkins, rhel-7

The goal is to start a docker image from a scripted jenkins pipeline.

The node running docker is RHEL7 machine.

On RHEL7 regular users aren't allowed to execute docker commands without sudo, see [this post by Dan Walsh](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/08/why-we-dont-let-non-root-users-run-docker-in-centos-fedora-or-rhel/).

Sudo has been configured and I set up the alias as recommended.
However jenkins doesn't read the bash profile.

Next I removed the alias and created a script called docker and placed that in directory which I now prepend to the PATH.

The pipeline is now able to execute docker but at the end of the pipeline it tries to call /usr/bin/docker-current and for some reason this doesn't use the script. Even though which docker-current in a sh step in the pipeline shows that it found the script.

All of this feels like I'm missing something.
How can I configure jenkins/docker so that jenkins is able to properly start docker images to run steps in my pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the Jenkins user sudo and trying to wrap calls to docker with sudo, add the Jenkins user to the docker group:

> If you don’t want to preface the docker command with sudo, create a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the Docker daemon starts, it creates a Unix socket accessible by members of the docker group.

[Source from the official documentation with more detailed instructions on giving non-root users access to the docker daemon.](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/#manage-docker-as-a-non-root-user)

These instructions are what I followed to give Jenkins docker access on RHEL 7 via scripted Pipelines and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: As Dan Walsh explains in the post I linked to this poses security risks. My goal is to allow jenkins to run docker containers without exposing this securoty risk.

Comment: Giving the Jenkins user sudo creates security risks too.  At some point you have to accept that allowing an agent to run a setuid executable is going to expose attack surfaces no matter how you do it.